# Drogon: how to use execSqlCoro? What headers to include?

Tags: c++

I'm tryin to use the `execSqlCoro` function of [Drogon](https://github.com/drogonframework/drogon). However, I am getting an error:

```
error: unable to find the promise type for this coroutine
   26 |   auto municipalities = co_await db->execSqlCoro(
```

What headers to I have to include to get the correct promise type?

See tests [here](https://github.com/drogonframework/drogon/blob/745535541939461dc16e3c16b46839bd13e4f7e4/orm_lib/tests/db_test.cc). I tried

```
#include <drogon/orm/DbClient.h>
#include <drogon/orm/CoroMapper.h>
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of Drogon's coroutine subsystem. I'm sorry for the confusion. That error message shows up when you didn't mark the function that calls the coroutine having return type as `Task<T>` (or to be accurate, an *awaitable* type that is compatible with Drogon or cppcoro's coroutine concept). For example the following function:

```cpp
void test()
{
    co_await drogon::sleepCoro(app().getLoop(), 1);
}
```

generates the error:

```cpp
error: unable to find the promise type for this coroutine
   17 |     co_await drogon::sleepCoro(app().getLoop(), 1);
      |     ^~~~~~~~
```

This requirement is documented in [Drogon's coroutine document](https://drogon.docsforge.com/master/coroutines/#using-coroutines).

> Just know that if you want the coroutine to yield something typed T. Then the return type will be Task<T>.

Thus the the solution is to have a return type of `Task<T>`

```cpp
using namespace drogon;
Task<void> test()
{
    co_await sleepCoro(app().getLoop(), 1);
}
```

---

Now, why this is required. To put it very simply (and I'm forecasting C++ veterans will correct me). In C++, the coroutine body (the code that runs) has almost nothing to do with how the coroutine is executed (controlled by `return_type::promise_type`).

Drogon provides 2 main execution modes. `Task<T>` and `AsyncTask`. Where `Task<T>` executes the coroutine body upon `co_await` while `AsyncTask` runs immediately, cannot be awaited and abort when exception escapes (so don't use `AsyncTask` unless you know what you are doing).

For example, the coroutine `foo` always waits for 0.1 seconds then prints "hello". But we can when and how the coroutine is executed by changing the return type.

```cpp
template <typename Awaiter>
Awaiter foo() 
{
    co_await sleepCoro(app().getLoop(), 0.1);
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}

// foo<Task<void>>();       // Nothing happens since we didn't await it.
foo<AsyncTask>();           // Waits 0.1 second then print
co_await foo<Task<void>>(); // Waits 0.1 second then print

auto awaiter = foo<Task<void>>();
std::cout << "hi, ";
co_await awaiter;           // Prints "hi, ". Waits 0.1 second then print "hello"
```

Thus the compiler complains when it can't find the `promise_type` to determine how to execute the coroutine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That clears things up a bit. I tried using coroutines in a `HttpSimpleController` but I'm guessing it's not possible since the return type of the virtual method doesn't match anymore then.

Comment: Found out I can use `drogon::async_run([=]() -> Task<void> {});`!

Comment: @BartLouwers I recommend using `HttpController` instead of `HttpSimpleController`. It allows you to directly have `Task<>` as the return type of the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable c++20 when compiling?

Comment: Yes. Using gcc 11.1.0 and C++20. `__cpp_impl_coroutine` is defined so coroutines are enabled.